# Using LINQ query result for data source for GridControl c#

Tags: c#, linq, datagrid

I have a function like this in a static class

```
public static IEnumerable<MyObject> getFilteredList(int docType)
{
    var fItems = from i in list
                 where i.DocType == docType
                 select i;

    return fItems;
}
```

When I use this returned list for a data source to my Grid in the form like this for example:

```
GridControl.DataSource = staticClass.getFilteredList(10)
```

The Grids `DataSource` property is null. Can you explain me why this is happening ?

Edit: the list variable is List which contains elements with DocType = 10.
The Items contains elements.

Comment: are you using databind() after that ?

Comment: wpf or winforms? form your code you assign linq iterator to datasource not a `List`. Try if adding `ToArray()` or `ToList()` would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
GridControl.DataSource = staticClass.getFilteredList(10).ToList();
```

to create a new `List` instance to bind to your grid.

Another way is to use a [`BindingList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx), which fully supports databinding and gives you usefull events like [`ListChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132742.aspx) and [`AddingNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132741.aspx).

```
var list = new BindingList(staticClass.getFilteredList(10).ToList());

GridControl.DataSource = list;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
GridControl.DataSource = staticClass.getFilteredList(10).ToList();
```

because DataSource must be inherited from IList

Answer (score 2):

You ca try with ToList()

```
GridControl.DataSource = staticClass.getFilteredList(10).ToList();
GridControl.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<MyObject> getFilteredList(int docType)
    {
        var fItems = from i in list
                     where i.DocType.docTypeId == docType
                     select i;

        return fItems;
    }
```

correct me if I am wrong but right now it seems as if you are comparing an int with the DocType class. if that's not the case then your query could just be returning an empty set since it can't find anything that matches.