# Filter Generic List by multiple values

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

There is a generic list of documents, how can i filter it by doc id 1 and 2.

I have tried following Linq but it is not working. I need to filter list and use it as a data source.

```
List<VisitDocs> listD = default(List<VisitDocs>);
result = from docs in listDwhere docs.DocID == 1 && docs.DocID == 2docs;

rptDocs.DataSource = listD;
```

Comment: listD.Where(n => n.DocID == 1 || docs.DocID == "2docs");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `||`:

```
result = listD.Where(doc=> doc.DocID == 1 || doc.DocID == 2);
```

or

```
result = from docs in listD where docs.DocID == 1 || docs.DocID == 2 select docs;
```

Your `DocID` could be `1` or `2`, It can't be both. Your current condition is using `&&` which would mean that it must be `1` and `2` at the same time.

For assigning `DataSource` call `ToList` like:

```
rptDocs.DataSource = result.ToList();
```

Comment: can i use result in data source afterward?

Comment: @user1263981, you should call `ToList()` on the query before assigning it to the `DataSource`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901264/using-linq-query-result-for-data-source-for-gridcontrol-c-sharp

Comment: i have tried with ToList but it is giving zero results.

Comment: @user1263981, are you sure there are records with ID `1` **or** `2`

Answer (score 1):

`docs.DocID == 1 && docs.DocID == 2` can never be true: if the value is 1, it's not 2, and vice versa. You need to use `||` (or), not `&&` (and)

Answer (score 0):

Please, change && to || and see if it works

Answer (score -1):

I think you tried to write something like this :

```
var result = (from docs in listD
             where docs.DocID == 1 || docs.DocID == 2
             select docs).ToList();

rptDocs.DataSource = result;
```

Where listD is your original list. Please note that in your code sample, ListD will be empty.

If you wish results with both DocID values 1 and 2, simply replace "&&" by "||". With "&&" it means that any *single* result should valid both conditions, which is impossible : a single result will have DocID equals to 1, or 2, or anything else. So if you want to take every result with 1 "or" 2, you should use the OR logical operator.

Comment: I'm very, very tired of users of SO who downvotes posts without explaining why, since my answer is certainly good and helpful. Downvotes with no comments should cost at least 10 rep at each time...

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I assume it's because the code you posted is still using `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: Maybe. But my post covers that also. Firstly, I had fixed the typos in question which makes code uncompilable, and also commented the operator problem. Since it certainly can't work like this, we can assume the OP actually wants a ||. I've edited my post to fix directly the operator...